# How to replace all the zeros in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I replace all the zeroes with asterisks in a string?

I've tried:

```
var a = "00000004567";
a.replace(/0*\d/g,'*');
```

The problem is that it returns: `"****567"`, which is undesirable.

Comment: `var a = 00000004567` - that wont have zeros, did you mean `var a = "00000004567"`

Comment: @JaromandaX actually it was a number instead a string, I had to convert it to a string in order to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

```
var a = '00000004567';
a.replace(/0/g, '*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `*\d` to convert all the zeroes to asterisks. The `g` modifier will handle the rest.

```js
var a = "00000004567";

console.log(a.replace(/0/g, '*'))
```

Comment: I had to convert it to a string in order to make it work, but that did the job, thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about a string, use the global modifier like this:

`a.replace(/0/g,"*");`